# Video is cutting off the end when transcoding

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to convert the MOV file to mp4 using the VLC transcoding, I am using the LIBVLC NuGet package in Dot Net Framework. But when I see the output video, it is cutting off at the end around by 30 sec.

my code is

`static void Main(string[] args)
{
try
{

```
            var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            WriteToFile("currentDirectory : " + currentDirectory);
            Console.WriteLine(currentDirectory);

            //Default installation path of VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows
            var libDirectory =
                new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));
            Console.WriteLine(libDirectory);
            WriteToFile("libDirectory : " + libDirectory);

            using (var mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
            {
                WriteToFile("In Using : " + mediaPlayer);

                var mediaOptions = new[]
                {
                ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=avc1,vb=1024,fps=70,acodec=mpga,ab=128}:std{mux=mp4,dst=D:\\AVC1_transcoded.mp4,access=file}",
                ":sout-keep"
                };
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"D:\video_20220120003955_0.mov");
                mediaPlayer.SetMedia(file, mediaOptions);

                mediaPlayer.Play();
                //Console.WriteLine($"Recording in {destination}");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {

        }
    }`
```

I am taking help from https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help and tried almost every syntax but didn't find any help.

Comment: I suspect you're pulling the rug before the encoding is complete, but without any actual code (rather than a snippet of config), you're unlikely to get any meaningful help here.

Comment: @MickyD It is in  .NET with c#. I am putting the whole code so that you can get an idea.

Comment: @spender Sure I have updated and put the whole code.

Comment: Shouldn't Console.ReadKey(); be after the using statement completes. The VlcMediaPlayer does not get disposed till your press a key.